# Troubleshooting Textbook: Using Generating Functions for Non-Homogenous Recurrence

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, quadratics, recursion

I am learning about Generating Functions to solve non-homogenous linear recurrences, and I can't seem to get the right solution, no matter what I do.

Also, the example I have to work off of in the text book has an error...and for the life of me, (well, for a few hours now anyway) I can't figure it out/get a working solution for $r_n$ for either the example recursion, or any of the practice recursions at the end of the chapter...

---

Here is the setup in the textbook:

[image]

And it continues with the problem on the next page:

[image]

And, finally, the solution:

[image]

---

The correct sequence is:

$$
r_n = 2^n + r_{n-1} + 2r_{n-2}, \text{ such that }r_0 = 2, r_1 = 1\text{ yielding: }\\
\{2,1,9,...\}
$$

While the solution in the book yields (from the wolfram alpha input posted below):

$$
\{3,4,14,30,...\}
$$

Wolfram Alpha input:

> (17/9)2^n + (2/3)n*2^n + (10/9)(-1)^n, for n = {0,1,2,3}

---

I thought I spotted a typo where the author said $\frac{1}{(1-2x)} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^n x^n \text{ instead of } \frac{1}{(1-2x)} - (1 + 2x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^n x^n$, but that didn't pan out either.

I'm not really sure where else the error could be...

---

Also, wolfram alpha gives a solution for the recursion,

> in: r_n - r_{n-1} - 2*r_{n-2} = 2^n such that r_0 = 2 and r_1 = 1
>   out: 
>   $ r_n = c_1(-2)^{n-1} + \frac{1}{9}(2^n(4(-1)^n - 9) + 3n + 5)$
>
> in: -4(-2)^(n-1) + (1/9)(2^n(4(-1)^n - 9) + 3n +5) for n = {0,1,2,3}

Where I use the only constant, $c_1$ to set $r_0$ to 2...

> out: {2,-6,7,-26,...}

I think that if I have at least one working example, I will be set...

Also, solved it using the advancement operator, and got:

$ \frac{n2^n}{6} + \frac{8}{9}2^n + \frac{10}{9}(-1)^n$

which yields: $\{2,1,6,10\}$, so at least that is close (I probably made a mistake somewhere)...but I think I need at least one working solution to this thing to get the hang of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did catch an error on the righthand side, and that error is the source of the problems:

$$\sum_{n\ge 2}2^nx^n=\frac{4x^2}{1-2x}\;.$$

This means that

$$\begin{align*}
R(x)&=\frac{4x^2}{(1-2x)(1-x-2x^2)}+\frac{2-x}{1-x-2x^2}\\
&=\frac{6x^2-5x+2}{(1-2x)^2(1+x)}\\
&=\frac19\left(\frac{-1}{1-2x}+\frac{6}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{13}{1+x}\right)\\
&=\frac19\sum_{n\ge 0}\big(-2^n+6(n+1)2^n+13(-1)^n\big)x^n\\
&=\frac19\sum_{n\ge 0}\big((6n+5)2^n+13(-1)^n\big)x^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

so that

$$r_n=\frac{(6n+5)2^n+13(-1)^n}9\;.$$

This does yield the correct values of $2,1,9$, and $19$ for $n=0,1,2$, and $3$, respectively.

Comment: Awesome.  so multiplying by $4x^2$ rather than using the subtraction keeps things more composed.

Comment: @bordeo: It seemed simplest just to write down the sum of the righthand series directly, since it's just geometric; starting with the sum from $n=0$ and subtracting the two missing terms offers more chances to make computational errors.